# if branches in Flow

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Why doesn't the following type-check in Flow:

```
var v: number = (function() {if (true) return 0;})();
```

Try it [here](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVA3AhgJzBgLjADsBXAWwCMBTPAXjAAopTiBjAFwEs5jGBKMAG8uUJhxylqgnNQ6kcxMAAYA3AF9+A1UA).

I know of the following ways to fix it:

- by removing the `if (true)`
- by changing the return type to `?number`
- by writing `if (true) return 0; else throw new Error()`
- by silencing the warning.

My questions are:

**(a)** what is the reason this is implemented by Flow in this manner?

**(b)** what is the most idiomatic way to address this problem?

I also get that `if` conditions cannot, in the general case, be evaluated statically and that `if` conditions that statically evaluate to either `true` or `false` shouldn't appear in production code. But Flow is a type checker, not a coding style enforcer, right?

Moreover, I still think that there are legitimate cases that this kind of pattern may arise. E.g.:

```
var someCondition;
someCondition = true;
if (someCondition) {
    var v: number = (function() {
        if (someCondition)
            return 1;
    })();
}
```

Try it [here](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVZNgG4EMBOYAznALYCmAwnAHYAmAlgC4O0DcGWJF19zrNMAF4wTfAFdyHLGAZQwACm5VajFrQCUYAN6cZmPIWwAuMDXGkARuUIiFUcTQDG6mgq279X2fKVkVfK4aet5e+ORM4viCAIzS3gC+Gu7xmAlAA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flow does not to static analysis of actual runtime code, so it does not know that `if (true)` means that the `else` branch does not execute. You'll have to write your code such that it is clear to Flow with code as

```
var v: number = (function() {
  if (true) return 0;
  throw new Error();
})();
```

Your `throw` may never run, but it makes it clear to Flow that it either returns a number or throws.

Comment: I've upvoted this answer but I don't believe the terminology "static analysis of actual runtime code" is precise or accurate. Could you please elaborate or improve your terminology? The way I see it, since `(true)` is a literal there's nothing that could or should prevent a static code analyzer from deducing that the `else` part is never going to be executed.

Comment: I'm not saying Flow _couldn't_ do that, just that it doesn't currently. Flow sees that it is a boolean value, but it doesn't know what `true` vs `false` means at runtime for cases like this.